# File access retry timeout (ASP.NET WebPages/Razor/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity

I keep getting the Keyword not supported: 'file access retry timeout' error when viewing pages that access my database.

So I'm assuming it can't access the database. I had this exact same problem just a few moments ago, when viewing my homepage. I changed (in my _AppStart.cshtml file) this:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MYDB", etc, etc, etc, etc);
```

to:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\MYDB.sdf", "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", etc, etc, etc, etc);
```

and it worked!

*However*, when I go to another page, (which tried to access the database from a C# Class, (.cs file) I get the same error!

But, in my C# file (.cs) - I cannot change:

```
var database = Database.Open("MYDB");
```

to:

```
var database = Database.Open("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\MYDB.sdf", "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", etc, etc, etc, etc);
```

... because it says:

No overload for method 'Open' takes 2 arguments (obviously).

The error (before making the above change in the .cs file:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Keyword not supported: 'file access retry timeout'.    Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported:
>   'file access retry timeout'.
>
> Source Error:

```
> 
> Line 161:     foreach(string item in items) Line 162:     { Line 163:         var
> row = database.QuerySingle("select Suburb, State from
> SuburbsPostCodesAndStates where Suburb = @0", item); Line
> 164:          if(row != null) Line 165:           {
>
```

> Source File: 
>   c:\HostingSpaces\jpezzime\mysite.com\wwwroot\App_Code\JTSi.cs
>   Line:  163
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'file access retry
>   timeout'.]
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String
>   keyword) +198
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String
>   keyword, Object value) +31
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value) +185
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String
>   connectionString) +181
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value) +241
>   WebMatrix.Data.DbProviderFactoryWrapper.CreateConnection(String
>   connectionString) +96
>   WebMatrix.Data.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_14()
>   +16    WebMatrix.Data.Database.get_Connection() +19    WebMatrix.Data.Database.EnsureConnectionOpen() +13
>   WebMatrix.Data.d__0.MoveNext() +72
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4232212
>
>   WebMatrix.Data.Database.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] args)
>   +98    JTSi.FindSetAndRemoveLocation(List`1 items) in c:\HostingSpaces\jpezzime\mysite.com\wwwroot\App_Code\JTSi.cs:163
>   ASP._Page_Shared_Pages_Search_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\HostingSpaces\jpezzime\mysite.com\wwwroot\Shared\Pages\Search.cshtml:17
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +208
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1
>   executors) +68    System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>   +123    System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +19    System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +67
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +19
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +67
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +121
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Can anybody please help shed some light on this? I have absolutely no idea how a website can go from totally awesome, to totally screwed up, in just a matter of minutes - when I haven't even made any changes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

replace:

```
var database = Database.Open("MYDB");
```

with:

```
var database = Database.OpenConnectionString("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\MYDB.sdf", "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with your connection string - [“File Access Retry Timeout”](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/03/sql-server-compact-40-sp1-ctp1.html) is a new keyword that was added to a newer version of SQL Compact.  You may be running an older version of it on the server.

Comment: Thank you 48klocs. I just found the OpenConnectionString method right after I posted the question. I tried it and it worked. Nice to know though, I wonder how new it is, because everything was working just great about half an hour ago :/ Ah well, it works now :)

Comment: @Jason the drawback to using OpenConnectionString is that it ignores the one you have configured in your web.config file - if your database location/version/connection options happen to change, it means you've got to recompile and redeploy, rather than tweaking a line in a config.  There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, but it's something to be aware of as code overriding config settings is often surprising behavior.

Comment: thank you, I wasn't aware of that. I just finished reading the link you posted, and from what I can tell, all I need to do is just download the new CP1 from the link provided and install it so it updates?

Comment: I just ran the MSI file included in that download, and it turns out that I already have a newer version.